# IE9 sees XML nodes at different indexes than other browsers

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

Here is a snippet from my attempt at cross-browser functionality:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/wp-content/testimonials.xml", true);

if (xmlhttp.addEventListener) {
    xmlhttp.addEventListener("load", retrieveTestimonial, false);
}
else if (xmlhttp.attachEvent) {
    xmlhttp.attachEvent("onload", retrieveTestimonial);
}

xmlhttp.send();

function retrieveTestimonial () {
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    //Get DOM elements ready to be replaced by relevant testimonial info
    var testimonial = document.getElementById("foot-testimonial");
    var xmlTags = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("PROGRAM");
    ... more
```

The reason I included this particular block of code is because my script renders just fine in Chrome, Firefox, IE11, Safari, and even the stock Android browser. However, in IE9 I'm getting undefined for some variables that are set in the `retrieveTestimonial` function. If I try to log any of those variables (xmlTags, etc.) out to the console in IE9 I get `'is undefined'`. So, from what I can tell, the function is not being called which suggests to me that the XHR load event is not firing.

EDIT: The function is firing, as I am able to log the variable `xmlDoc` to the console (object). For some reason, IE9 does not like some of my XML assignments because they are returning undefined. Here is the rest of the function:

```
for(var i = 0; i < xmlTags.length; i++) {

    //If the program name from the URL matches the <WEBTITLE> value
    if (progName == xmlTags[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue) {

        // Get each relevant piece of info from the XML file
        var progTitle = xmlTags[i].childNodes[3].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var studentName = xmlTags[i].childNodes[5].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var textBody = xmlTags[i].childNodes[7].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        break;
    }
```

IE9 does not seem to like seeing nodes at the same index as other browsers, though I haven't a clue as to why.

Is there a known workaround for this or am I just missing something simple? I'd hate to rewrite the script in jQuery, for instance, considering it's working like a charm everywhere else.

Comment: I have also tried adding: `else if (xmlhttp.onload) { retrieveTestimonial(); }` to no avail.

Comment: I know older IE's does not support attachEvent on the XMLHttpRequest object and I am thinking IE9 did not support the progress events.

Comment: I've been doing some more reading... is `onreadystatechange` the way to go with this?

Comment: That would be the old school way, checking for readyState of 4

Comment: `onreadystatechange` method works in all other browsers but still not IE9. I'm starting to see why some full-time web dev's loathe this browser.

Comment: what do you mean it does not in IE9, all browsers support onreadystatechange.

Comment: I mean that when I check the `readyState` and `status` instead of using load events it is working on all other browsers but still not calling my function in IE9.

Comment: How are you adding the event? It should just by `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){};`

Comment: Exactly the way you've described. It works in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but not IE9.

Comment: Well does it get triggered? console.log is your friend. What is the status? Errors in the console? What is the exact code you are using?

Comment: Actually, this is interesting. Note the code in the original post - console.log(xmlDoc); yields `object`. So I was mistaken; the function IS getting triggered. For some reason, IE9 does not like the other assignments, though.

Comment: `var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement;`

Comment: How will that differ from calling `.getElementsByTagName()` on the responseXML doc? It works in all the other browsers. It's like IE9 skips right to trying to get the info before the XML is actually ready - I can run the variable assignments in the console after the DOM is loaded and it works.

Comment: What is your updated code? How is it different than the code above or is it the same?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47024/discussion-between-armadadrive-and-epascarello)